# Simple slideshow program: captions, local image files, sequence

Tags: windows, presentation, slideshow, photography

After googling for a while, I have to ask the only people I trust :) Here are my specific requirements for a slideshow program:

1. It should use locally saved original images as its source (i.e., not render everything into a movie) 
   1a. Because it should be easy to change (add/remove images)
2. It should be possible to set up a "scenario" - a sequence it will keep to
3. It should be possible to show captions and define duration for each, i.e. say "Summer vacation 2013" over all the images from step N until N+m of the sequence.
4. (Secondary) a pleasant transition effect would be nice, but enough with just a fader or something, nothing fancy.

Most important is sequence and captions. So far I can only think of sticking everything into Premiere and creating a sequence, putting captions on top and call it done, but it violates p. 1 and makes it rather inflexible. Should I want to add a single image I'd have to do some relatively complex editing, and worst of all, re-rendering the whole sequence.

It does not have to be gratis, but hopefully reasonably priced.

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system should it run on?

Comment: Windows (8-ish)

Comment: A browser-based alternative: [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js)

Answer (score 1):

[Boxoft](http://www.boxoft.com/photo-slideshow/) has developed a slideshow builder that provides most, if not all, of what you want.  Their product supports 35+ image formats and provides multiple ways of creating your slideshow (eg. as an .exe, burnt to a cd, or dvd movie).  It provides an explorer type UI that allows you to add and manage images, change the order, and set transitions.  I use their Flash variant of this product to produce a slideshow on a web site.  You can download a trial version to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Looks interesting, yes - thank you. Unfortunately they don't seem to have captions, which is a bit critical for me. So I guess I will keep looking.

Comment: You should double check that. The flash version I use does have captions. I think you need to mouse over them to display.